# Angular 4 - Primeng Datatable - Edit and detail in the same row

Tags: angular, primeng-datatable

I am using ng prime DataTable to show data in a html table.

In the same row of my DataTable I can edit row and see detail in modals windows.

This is the html code:

```
<p-dataTable (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)" [value]="registers" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedRegister">
    <p-column>
        <ng-template pTemplate="body">
            <a (click)="editRegister(register)"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </ng-template>
    </p-column>
    <p-column field="name" header="Name" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

The problem is that when I click on the whole row, the function    `onRowSelect` is executed but when I click on icon "fa-pencil" both functions
 `editRegister` and 
   `onRowSelect` are executed, but i want to execute only `editRegister` on click of edit(pencil icon) button.

How to achieve this ? 
thanks in advance

Comment: I have up with a temporary solution, for the moment hidden the modal I do not need when I go to the editRegister function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you still need a better solution you can try to add event.stopPropagation in your editRegister function
(don't forget to pass event in parameters of course)